# html download file chunks from multiple urls as if it was 1 file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to split a file in multiple chunks and host each chunk on a different url or server, is it possible to then kinda trick the client as if it's downloading a file from a singular url? (without changing the way the servers are hosting the file)

I'd like to do this with a video file so I could use it in an html video element as source but streamed from multiple servers.

Plan B would be creating a custom video player and changing the source as needed but that would never really be seamless.

Comment: Yes it's doable, but why do you want to do this? If you are trying to protect your file from being stolen, that won't work. If you want this for an other reason, would be good to say it, as the solution would greatly depend on your case.

Comment: @Kaiido My video hosting options are a max file size of 50mb (can be any filetype tho), don't ask me why. This is the situation I need to deal with.

Comment: Ok, and you can't change this setting? Would be easier. If you can't, can you clarify if you need to be able to seek inside this video, and if waiting for having downloaded everything is ok.

Comment: I can't change it. I'm looking for the exact same behaviour as a regular html5 video player streaming a video file. Basically all I can do is host the files as either cut-up mp4's off the original video or raw data chunks.

Comment: This can't really be done. The media-player of your browser needs all the resouce to be served from the same address. However, you can implement your own streaming player , à la YouTube for instance, but that's a lot of work. The easy solution is to prefetch everything and build the final video on client, but this means a long download phase before being able to play anything. I unfortunately don't have much time right now to write a proper answer,  but I will in the next day or so if no-one came by.

Comment: If it's really not possible then I guess I'll attempt to use multiple video tags with custom controls and kinda show/hide tags based on which chunk should be played.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really have the same behavior as browsers' one in an easy way.

You have to understand that browsers are quite smart when displaying medias, and that they have access to information we mere js-activators don't.
First, when they do display a media, they will search for the metadata. These are usually either at the beginning of the file, either at its end (and maybe sometimes somewhere else, but that's more rare on the web).
So they start by doing a [*range request*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) at the beginning in the hope of being able to parse the file's metadata, if not found, they'll search at the end.
Once they get these metadata, they know at what position are each block of data relative to the media's timestamp. They can thus request from the server only the bytes needed to display the time requested by the user.
That's how you can seek farther than what got already fetched; when the seek has been done, the browser cancels its previous request and makes a new one for the byte-range containing the data at the requested time (if not already fetched).

The browser is responsible of the fetching, and decoding part, so both can communicate together and this setup is possible. However, **we** don't have access to the decoding part, all we can do is fetching data, and serve it to the browser's decoder.

This means that to be able to do what you want to do, we would need to know how our files are generated in order to be able to make ourself the correct *range-requests* based on user's seek operation.

This is doable, this is actually what most video service like YouTube do in order to serve the variable media quality.
You can use a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) to serve your data to the browser's decoder just like if it was a stream coming from a server.
The fact that the data is served as a stream also implies that you will have to build your own User-Interface to let them seek where they want. I hope you will understand I won't do it in this answer, but rather stay at a very high level.

---

---

And even though it will probably not fit your needs, I have to include the lazy way, which consists in downloading the full media and building it in the user's computer memory. 
This has the big disadvantage of not being able to do any range-request, and thus your users have to **download the whole file** before being able to start playing it, which is not a good idea if your users are on slow networks, but it has the advantage of being über easy to implement:

```js
// some URLs
const path = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/",
  file1 = "f945qd8gju2x5y6/part_1.mp4",
  file2 = "qs3us6qve32jjju/part_2.mp4"
console.log('begin to fetch, please be patient');
// fetch all the different parts
Promise.all([
  fetch(path + file1).then(r=>r.blob()),
  fetch(path + file2).then(r=>r.blob())
])
// merge in a single Blob
.then(arr => new Blob(arr)) 
// display from memory
.then(blob => vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob))
.then(_ => console.log('ready to play'));
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls></video>
```